# Нужна ли запятая перед «помогите»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

*Мне страшно(,) помогите!*
Нужна ли запятая перед "помогите", если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Мне страшно, помогите!*

Конечно же, в этом сложном предложении (без подлежащих!), состоящем из односоставных простых предложений, указанная запятая ставится (по общему правилу — между двумя простыми предложениями в составе сложного).

***Мне страшно** (мне больно; мне грустно*) — это безличное предложение.
***Помогите** (позвоните завтра; смотрю внимательно*) — определенно-личное предложение (глагол-сказуемое ставится в форме 1-го или 2-го лица настоящего или будущего времени, повелительного наклонения).

> — Александр Егорович, ну почему мы Вас не слушались? Теперь он мёртв, его убило чудовище. Оно будет охотиться на нас и не успокоится, пока не утащит в ужасный колодец. **Мне страшно, помогите,** я не хочу умирать.
> [Александр Назаркин. Аноптикус](https://books.google.ee/books?id=xQzJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&dq=%22%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%22&source=bl&ots=Y-0y6bqjmy&sig=ACfU3U3pATDoBPJJPs5bKX47UTT2cYokFg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivzqjSmuPzAhXokYsKHWJWC-E4KBDoAXoECA4QAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%22&f=false)

[Типы односоставных предложений](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/tipy-odnosostavnyh-predlozheniy.html)

Comment: Уф! За **что** именно минус-то? Разве запятая не нужна? Разве предложение не сложное? Разве простые предложения я неправильно "обозвала"? Или пример не в тему? Повторно взываю: минусовщики, объясняйтеся! Все хоть будем знать, в чем дело.

Comment: Снова такая же ситуация: минусовщик считает, что Вы не должны отвечать на вопросы, которые мог бы решить сам задающий.  А @Liads1 продолжает спрашивать и никак не отмечает ответы (только один плюс и один принятый)...

Comment: Но ведь вопрос никто даже и не пытался закрыть. Да, конечно, он несложный. Но мне самой было интересно вспомнить классификацию односоставных предложений, все это обкрутить и закончить подходящим примером. Разве ж это плохо? Другие прочитают, — поучатся. И разве ж вопросы *всегда* должны быть затейливыми или головоломными? Я не права, Александр?

Comment: Римма, **абсолютно** согласен! Тем более что вопрос не из разряда элементарных.